# ganglia, No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python, ganglia

I currently add some metrics to ganglia python plugin which monitor MySQL status.

It has been working for a long time. after modifying the mysql.py, I restart gmond, and log shows

```
[PYTHON] Can't import the metric module [mysql].
```

I run `gmond -m` and get the result:

```
[PYTHON] Can't import the metric module [mysql].

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ganglia/python_modules/mysql.py", line 49, in <module>
  import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I can import MySQLdb in python cli, what's the problem?

Comment: Long shot, but is Ganglia using the same Python executable as you do on the terminal? I would put in this mysql.py a line 'print sys.executable'.

Comment: I finally know the cause, my system upgrade from ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04, ganglia was using old python2.6 while MySQLdb was installed in python2.7

Answer (score 0):

My system upgrade from ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04, ganglia was using old python2.6 while MySQLdb was installed in python2.7.

I reinstall ganglia-monitor and the problem is solved.